# know the address of Arduino ethernet shield through public ip

Tags: arduino, gps, ethernet, public-method

Yes, like I wrote the ask title. I want to know it is possible know or see the someway the approximate geolocalization through public ip.

I have an arduino with ethernet shield.

Thanks, I've been searching for many days, but I wasn't found anything.

Thanks for read my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an online API to obtain an estimation of your current geolocation, this one looks decent to me: http://ip-api.com/.

As a quick overview of the [documentation](http://ip-api.com/docs/), you have to send a GET request to one of the format urls (json, xml, line, ...) and it will send back the geolocation. The easiest one to use is probably [line](http://ip-api.com/line).

Comment: Mmm doesn't sense

Comment: Is there anything specific you don't understand?